# I have a problem creating a diary with Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I am making a diary with Django.

**urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
    
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.diary_index, name = "diary-index"),
    path('<int:month>/', views.diary_date , name = "diary-date"),
    path('<int:month>/<int:day>/', views.diary_list, name = "diary-list")
```

**views.py**

```py
def diary_date(request, month) :
    day = HaruDiary.objects.filter(dt_created__month=month)
    context = {"month":month}
    return render(request, "change/diary_date.html", context)
 
def diary_list(request, month, day) :
    day = HaruDiary.objects.filter(dt_created__month = month, dt_created__day = day)
    context = {"day":day}
    return render(request, "change/diary_list.html", context)
```

**Month selection partial**

```html
<div id="month_section">
    {% for num in "x"|rjust:"12" %}
    <a class="month" href="{% url 'diary-date' forloop.counter %}">{{ forloop.counter }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**Day selection partial** (redirected from month selection)

```html
<a class = "date" href = "{% url 'diary-list' 1 1 %}">01</a>
```

I don't want to specify the month, but if I don't specify the month by putting int:month/int:day in urls.py, an error keeps popping up. Is there any way to fix this??..Please help...

I tried a lot of things through ChatGBT, but I wrote and deleted it, so I don't have any data. I'm sorry.

Comment: Please format your code properly. [edit] your code, select the code fragments and click on the "Code sample" button (`{}`) to format the code.

Comment: Please fix the indentation.